# Capture string between characters and replace

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to parse a QML file with Javascript, and make a JSON out of it.
I've encountered a problem that I cannot solve. 
I'm trying to replace every string of the file which isn't already between `"` and put it between  double `"`.
So if I have some strings like

```
Layout.fillHeight: true
height: 200
color: "transparent"
```

should become

```
"Layout.fillHeight": "true"
"height": 200"
"color": "transparent"
```

Here's the regex I've written, failingly miserably:

```
/((\S\.\S)|\w+?)(?![^"]*\")/g

(\S.\S)|w+? take every string (considering also words with . between them
```

Two problems:

1. If a line contains any string between 2 `"`, any words of that line is not considered.
2. With `replace()` I cannot replace the string because `$1` or `$2` are not containing the exact string I want to replace.

I'm not great with Regex, so if you guys could help me would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a fragment from JSON, so gotta ask: shouldn't you be fixing the JSON at its source?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Tim, read the first line: it's a QML file, and i'm trying to convert it into a JSON file.

Comment: `true` and `200` are valid JSON values.

Comment: Fair enough +1.  Do you have a tool in mind for this?

Comment: I know I know, I will take care of that, but by now I just want to replace the string as I asked.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm trying to make that.

Comment: Try [`(\S+)\s*:\s*(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/U2zz9L/1) and replace it with `"$1": "$2"`

Comment: Try [`/^(\s*)"?([^":\n]+)"?\s*:\s*"?(.*?)"?$/gm` and replace with `'$1"$2": "$3"'`](https://regex101.com/r/afiWew/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the REGEX @Tushar provided:

```
(\S+)\s*:\s*(\S+)
```

It's the one I was looking for. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Gets rid of all the quotes, reinserts at the start and end of each line, and goes on to replace the colon and space with the rest

```js
let string = `Layout.fillHeight: true
height: 200
color: "transparent"`

console.log(string.replace(/\"/g, "").replace(/^|$/gm, "\"").replace(/\:\ /gm, "\": \""))
```

As an alternative, if they are in an array format to begin with:

```js
function quotify(string) {
  let regex = /^\s*"?(.*?)"?:\s*"?(.*?)"?$/,
    matches = regex.exec(string);

  return `"${matches[1]}": "${matches[2]}"`;
}

let strings = ['Layout.fillHeight: true',
    'height: 200',
    'color: "transparent"'
  ],
  quotedStrings = [];

strings.forEach((string) => {
  quotedStrings.push(quotify(string))
})

let jsonString = JSON.parse(`{${quotedStrings}}`);


console.log(jsonString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Notepad++ solution using two replacements.  First double quote the keys, if necessary:

**Find:**

```
^([^":]+):
```

**Replace:**

```
"$1"
```

Then quote the values, again if necessary:

**Find:**

```
:\s+([^"]+)$
```

**Replace:**

```
"$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more involved solution that quotes only strings that aren't already quoted.

```js
var str = `Layout.fillHeight: true
height: 200
color: "transparent"`;

var result = str.split(/\n/).map((v) => {
  return v.split(/\s*\:\s*/).map((vv) => {
      if(!isNaN(vv) || vv == "true" || vv == "false" || (vv[0] == '"' && vv[vv.length - 1] == '"')){
          return vv;
      }
      return `"${vv}"`;
    }).join(":");
}).join(",");

console.log(JSON.parse(`{${result}}`));
```

I've probably made things more complicated then they have to be and it will most probably fail when processing constructs that I haven't considered.